# Dealing with files/folders with spaces in bash script

Tags: bash

I need to search for places.sqlite on a system which may have spaces in the folder name; This works without spaces in folder name:

```
    for each in `find /home/ -name "places.sqlite" | grep -i ".mozilla/firefox"` ;do
         echo "${each}"
    done
```

Which prints: /home/itsupport/.mozilla/firefox/d2gigsya.default/places.sqlite (for example)

However, if the folder contains spaces it chops up path to the file and breaks my script!

To recap, this type of folder WOULD work in the script:

```
    $ sudo find /home/ -name "places.sqlite" | grep -i ".mozilla/firefox"
    /home/itsupport/.mozilla/firefox/d2gigsya.default/places.sqlite
```

And this folder with spaces does NOT work in the script:

```
    $ sudo find /home/ -name "places.sqlite" | grep -i ".mozilla/firefox"
    /home/itsupport/.mozilla/firefox/Random Ass Location/places.sqlite
```

I know that you can use $(command) or something but I'm not sure what to do when I'm using the find as the loop variable.  Maybe that is my mistake here.  Anyway, any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` has the `-print0` flag to deal with this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    echo ${file}
done
```

Example:

```
$ ls
script.sh  space name
$ ./script.sh 
.
./script.sh
./space name
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me :                                                                                find /${1}/ -name "${2}" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file ;do

Comment: however the extra grep I had in there didn't work.  Figuring that part out now.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use IFS to split on line end, instead of any whitespace characters.

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for bla in ....
do
...
done
IFS="$oldIFS" # restoring to avoid surprising the rest of the script
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the files are in well-known locations, you can just use

```
for each in /home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*/places.sqlite
do echo "${each}"
done
```